# bottom nav not appearing correctly Vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am currently getting to know the vue framework with vuetify, and I am running into a couple issues here ... I have laid out a simple layout for the main page, but for whatever reason, the buttons do not fill the full height, and the background color is using (by default) the hover color. this is what it looks like:

[image: image of the layout with broken styling]

The Code:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar app> </v-app-bar>
    <v-main>
      <router-view />
    </v-main>
    <v-bottom-navigation app v-model="value">
      <v-btn value="cards" to="/cards">
        <span>Cards</span>
        <v-icon>mdi-cards</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn value="decks" to="/decks">
        <span>Decks</span>
        <v-icon>mdi-mail</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-bottom-navigation>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',

  data: () => ({
    value: 'cards',
  }),
}
</script>
```

it is quite odd that this is happening as the application will randomly fix itself every once in a while when deleting random lines of code, then when I try to change something on the navigation, it will then break again.

Comment: What theme you have set for the Vuetify?

Comment: I tested your code and its working fine. what's the issue?